# Why does getline fail in a C function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, getline

I'm creating a (very) basic shell - however, I was doing it on a haphazard basis using functions to change global variables - which I was advised not to do by older and wiser programmers- so I have set about changing this behaviour to return pointers to variables rather than changing global ones.

When my program runs getline, the pointer to which the data is read in returns empty, causing it to crash when I take a copy of the string later. I know the getline is working correctly - however the result is lost when leaving the method. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much!

```
#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

int readcmd(char* cmd, size_t nBytes);

int argCount = 0; //Counter of number of arguments

int readcmd(char *cmd, size_t nBytes) {

    int ret = getline(&cmd, &nBytes, stdin);

    printf("%s", cmd); //This prints correctly
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    const size_t nBytes = 64; //Data type representing size of objects (unsigned)

    char *cmd = NULL; //Pointer to input string
    char *cmdCpy = NULL;

    int bytesRead = -1;
    char prompt[] = "DaSh-> ";

    while (1) {

        printf("%s", prompt); //Print prompt

        bytesRead = -1;
        while (bytesRead == -1) {
            bytesRead = readcmd(cmd, nBytes); //While no bytes read, loop
        }

        printf("%s", cmd); //This prints "(null)" - data lost!?

        cmdCpy = malloc((sizeof(char) * bytesRead) + 1);
        strcpy(cmdCpy, cmd);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `getline` modifies the local `cmd` variable of the `readcmd` function. This change is not visible outside of the function, so when control returns to `main`, the `cmd` variable there remains unmodified. The same is true for the `nBytes` variable.

To resolve this, you can pass the parameters to the `readcmd` function by pointer :

```
int readcmd(char **cmd, size_t *nBytes) {
    int ret = getline(cmd, nBytes, stdin);

    printf("%s", *cmd); //This prints correctly
    return ret;
}

bytesRead = readcmd(&cmd, &nBytes);
```

But you might as well have just called the `getline` function directly from `main`.

Comment: If `ret == -1`, what does `printf("%s", *cmd);` print?

Comment: BTW: Your good suggestion to pass the address of `nBytes` will cause trouble with `const size_t nBytes` as  does not that need to be `size_t nBytes`?

Comment: @chux : I assumed that `printf` was just there for debugging purposes, and would be removed in the release version. If that isn't the case, obviously, `ret` needs to be checked before trying to use `cmd`.

Comment: printf statements were there for me to try and work out where it wasn't working!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Beware with malloc((sizeof(char) * bytesRead) + 1) if bytesRead == -1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int readcmd(char **cmd, size_t *nBytes) {

    int ret = getline(cmd, nBytes, stdin);

    printf("%s", *cmd); //This prints correctly
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    const size_t nBytes = 64; //Data type representing size of objects (unsigned)

    char *cmd = NULL; //Pointer to input string
    char *cmdCpy = NULL;

    int bytesRead = -1;
    char prompt[] = "DaSh-> ";

    while (1) {

        printf("%s", prompt); //Print prompt

        bytesRead = -1;
        while (bytesRead == -1) {
            bytesRead = readcmd(&cmd, &nBytes); //While no bytes read, loop
        }

        printf("%s", cmd); //This prints "(null)" - data lost!?

        cmdCpy = malloc((sizeof(char) * bytesRead) + 1);
        strcpy(cmdCpy, cmd);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

**bytesRead = readcmd(&cmd, &nBytes)** You should pass adress if you want to keep data.

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program. (In this case, the value in *n is ignored.)

Comment: Grmph, MSVC has not those ... but you are right of course !

Answer (score 0):

The first time readcmd() is called the value of cmd is null and no storage has been allocated therefore getline() will fail.

Comment: Shouldnt do - to my limited knowledge getline allocates memory dynamically automatically